# C# Namespace issue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am new to C# and I wish to know how to use my own  namespace in c#.

Suppose I have a namespace MyNamespace1.

And I have another namespace MyNamespace2. I want to use MyNamespace1. But when I use

```
using MyNamespace1;
```

it is not recognizable.I want to know how to do this.

Comment: You would have to have at least one class in that namespace1, but perhaps you already have that.

Comment: just call MyNamespace1.className.functionName();

Comment: Is MyNamespace1 in a different project than MyNamespace2, or in the same?

Comment: If there in different projects you need there reference the project with namespace1 in it.

Comment: can you share the code were you are defining your namespace.and also is your project a website model or a webproject model?

Comment: Where do you have mynamspace2? in the same project? then its not a problem. but if you have in a different project, then you have to reference it. add the project to your references and then type "using"

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is your friend in learning about this.

```
The namespace keyword is used to declare a scope.
```

namespaces used to organize it's many classes

```
namespace N1     // N1
{
    class C1      // N1.C1
    {
        class C2   // N1.C1.C2
        {
        }
    }
    namespace N2  // N1.N2
    {
        class C2   // N1.N2.C2
        {
        }
    }
}
```

[Using Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx)

Check your accessibility level of your namespace. If it is in same project then you can access it directly.

```
using YourProjectName.NamespaceThatYouCreated;
```

If it is another project like `dll` etc then add reference to that library or project.
access namespace as:

```
using AnotherProject.CreatedNameSpacename;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

and this one in particular:
http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson06.aspx

Also, what I've discovered, if you're using asp.net you might need to change the property "Build action" of the class you wish to use in your page to "Compile".

Answer (score 0):

If both of your name spaces are in different project then you must add the reference of the other project to access it's namespace. In your case add the project reference of `MyNamespace1` to the project the project of `MyNamespace2`.